# Handling polyline dynamically in ngx-leaflet

Tags: typescript, leaflet, angular5, ngx-leaflet

I am trying to use polylines on ngx-leaflet but i'm having some issues.
First of all, I try to declare a polyline by passing a hardcoded latlng value it all works, but if I try to pass a variable ti gives me the following error:

```
   bubu = [[39.838128, 15.480699]];
    route= polyline([[39.838128, 15.480699]]); // ok
    routes= polyline(this.bubu); /*Argument of type 'number[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LatLngExpression[]'.
    Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'LatLngExpression'.
    Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'LatLngLiteral'.
    Property 'lat' is missing in type 'number[]'.*/
```

I've also tried to use the setLatLngs method to update the coordinates dynamically but it does not accept Marker[] as coordinates:

```
    markers: Marker[] = [];
    marker.push(/*a valid marker*/);
    marker.push(/*a valid marker*/);
    route= polyline( markers); /*: Argument of type 'Marker<any>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LatLngExpression[]'.
    Type 'Marker<any>' is not assignable to type 'LatLngExpression'.
    Type 'Marker<any>' is not assignable to type 'LatLngLiteral'.
    Property 'lat' is missing in type 'Marker<any>'.
*/
```

So I can I dynamically create a polyline and update with the library? The final purpose i'm trying to build is that the final user has the feature of creating markers and link them with polylines.

I want to make clear that i'm using only the standard 'ngx-leaflet' lib and not the others plugin.

Comment: You must pass `this.budu` by type: `LatLngExpression`. Please share `LatLngExpression` interface

Comment: It is not an interface that i've built, but is an internal interface built in ngx-leaflet

Comment: Click over this type it will moved you to declaration of this type. Check this and if you can share structure

Comment: Can you explain what are you saying?

Comment: What IDE do you use? Try find `LatLngExpression`

Comment: I think what they're trying to say is make sure you're typing the `this.budu` variable properly to be of type `LatLngExpression`. Your declaration of the variable should look like: `budu: LatLngExpression 
= [[39.838128, 15.480699]];`. You'll also need to import that type from leaflet.

Comment: Ok, but what if I have a Marker [  ] type and I need to get lat and lng from that array? Btw I am using Webstorm.

Comment: I have also found out a workaround to this problem but I want to wait for a better solution (tomorrow I am going to write the answer)